# Does html can be use with dynamic generated images in php?

Tags: php, html, gd

I am using this code to create an image

```
<?php

 // Set the content-type
 header('Content-Type: image/png');

 // Create the image
 $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

 // Create some colors
 $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
 $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
 $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
 imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

 // The text to draw
 $text = 'Testing...';
 // Replace path by your own font path
 $font = 'arial.ttf';

 // Add some shadow to the text
 imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

  // Add the text
  imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

  // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
  (A)print ('<div class="test">');
  imagepng($im);
  print ('</div>');
  (B)imagedestroy($im);
  ?>
```

The code work fines if i comment the line number 'A' and 'B' and it generates the image on the browser with testing written on it. But i want the image to be in a div. so i uncomment the line (A) and (B) but it is not giving right output. The generated html is also strange generated html is

```
<img src="http://localhost/php/test92.php" alt="The image “http://localhost/php/test92.php” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.">
```

Comment: you have to learn what HTML is and how it works. No offense, just a friendly suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, to create dynamic image in HTML, you will need 2 PHP files:

1. one for the image itself
2. another one for PHP to display it.

Let's take a look how to do it:

1. You create `image.php` that accept parameter, like: image ID or file name. For security reason, you HAVE to filter whatever parameter it get.

   > Why you have to do this? because, to generate image, you can't mix it with another HTML output. Let alone a single `space` or `return` as this will render the image broken.
2. You do the HTML thing on another PHP, say `test92.php`. To the HTML logic here, like:

   1. get image data
   2. loop the data
   3. display image => `<img src="image.php?imageID=12" alt="" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a div around your image you have to do that in the html, you can't do that in the image generation code

```
<div>
<img src="http://localhost/php/test92.php">
</div>
```

If you are getting errors regarding the image, try browsing the image url http://localhost/php/test92.php and see what it looks like.

Does it show an image like you are expecting?